# Putting # at the start of every line in a selected block, and removing

Tags: emacs

I am typing some code using emacs ,for example:

```
pi = 3.14
radius = 5
area = pi*radius**2
print area
```

and I want to comment out all 4 lines like so;

```
#pi = 3.14
#radius = 5
#area = pi*radius**2
#print area
```

Someone suggested to select the block, then ctrl+x r t # enter , but this is what I got;

```
#i = 3.14
#adius = 5
#rea = pi*radius**2
#rint area
```

It has replaced the first entry with a # . This would be fine if it could be reversed but the reversal method crtl+x r k just deletes everything.
I found something that works though which is a bit long drawn out. First select the position of the first # and type ctrl+x ( crtl+a # ctrl+n ctrl+x ). This will have put a # at the start of the first line. If you want to repeat this for Z number of lines now type crtl+u Z crt+x e. This will place a # at the start of the following Z lines.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but it looks like what you want to do is comment the lines you selected. In which case, run `M-x comment-region`

Comment: See also the library multiple cursors:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el  After watching the intro video, you may be hooked.

Comment: `M-;` is an even shorter way of doing it, and it comments all the languages I've tried it on (java, python, c). It also removes the comments if you run it again on the same region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> trick replaces the text in the rectangle bounded by point and mark, so this would actually work if you select from the first column of the first row, and then put point on the *first* column of the last row, i.e.:

```
<mark>pi = 3.14
radius = 5
area = pi*radius**2
<point>print area
```

Then it will "replace" the empty string at the beginning of each line with `#`.

Another way to do this is to mark the block you want to comment out and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd> (or `M-x comment-region`).  It's supposed to do the right thing for the programming language you're currently using.

As noted by lawlist in the comments, [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) is a rather addictive tool that can be useful in situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `C-x C-r t` here.  Use one of these instead:

- `comment-region` (I bind it to `C-x C-;`)
- `comment-dwim` (`M-;`)
- `string-insert-rectangle` -- if you have Emacs 24.4 or later (or a recent dev snapshot)